# BigQuery - Scheduled Query Update Delete via CLI

Tags: google-bigquery, gcloud

The BigQuery's Scheduled Query is an interesting one and for GCP to enable the creation of one programmatically via its CLI tool offers some flexibilities and conveniences. After creating a few SQs I realised, from time to time, updates needs to be done on one or several of the SQ.

The challenge here is finding a way to update/ or delete/ or enable/disable an existing scheduled query via the CLI. GCP's documentation clearly explained how one can create using either the `bq query` or `bq mk` command. There is absolutely nowhere to suggest we can delete or update/modify an existing scheduled query either via CLI or Python.

I was thinking of `bq rm` but there isn't a flag to specifically deletes a scheduled query. I may be risking dropping an entire dataset or table.

Perhaps it is a limitation at the moment. However, if anyone has found a way to do so, please share your solution or your way around.

Answer (score 1):

sorry for the confusion.

Scheduled query does support update/delete in CLI. Scheduled query is managed as a transfer config in CLI, please see [update transfer config](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/working-with-transfers#updating_a_transfer) and [delete transfer config](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/working-with-transfers#deleting_a_transfer).

For example, to update/delete a scheduled query with name `projects/p/locations/us/transferConfigs/scheduled_query`:

```
# Update the query parameter in a scheduled query.
bq update --transfer_config --params='{"query":"SELECT 1"}' projects/p/locations/us/transferConfigs/scheduled_query

# Delete a scheduled query.
bq rm --transfer_config projects/p/locations/us/transferConfigs/scheduled_query
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, could you help me learn a bit more about the issue here? The short answer is, scheduled queries do work with partitioned tables. Do you have partitioned table pre created before creating the scheduled query? Or do you want scheduled query to create the partition table for you? Also feel free to ping me on IM.

Comment: I'm not sure how to ping you on IM, you do not seem to have any contact information on your profile!? OK great, I already have a partitioned table setup, but when bringing in new data via BQ Data Transfer, this is when I'm having an issue. If it's best to create the partition when bringing in new data, then fine, we can do that. Really appreciate your help here, I'd be keen to get in touch. Marcus

Comment: Either way should work - creating the partitioned table ahead or let schedule query creating it. Are you creating ingestion time based partitioned table or column based partitioned table?

Comment: Without partitioning, the Transfer service works fine and updates the BQ Table (with new avro files). I've tried creating the BQ Table with partitioning by ingestion time, partition type by day. But then the Transfer update fails. Error: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Incompatible table partitioning specification. Expects partitioning specification interval (type: day), but input partitioning specification is; Job ID:xxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: Sorry this is a bug that should already been fixed right before New Year. Is it still happening for you?

Comment: Yes, it hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: Hello I have emailed you. Please open a support ticket with us so that you can provide us the job id there.